# Does any body have some statistics about the usage of scrollbar buttons(up and down) in a web page?

Tags: website-design, scrollbars

I wanted to know how much a user uses scrollbar buttons rather than the thumb? and possible cases when he goes for buttons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a heat map study from mozilla ui lab for the firefox browser. It's visualize the user behavior clearly.

[Mozilla UI lab heat map study](https://heatmap.mozillalabs.com/)

> Based on over 117,000 Windows 7 and Vista Test Pilot submissions from 7 days in July 2010
>
> - The Up arrow on the scrollbar was used on average by 27% of users.
> - The Down arrow was used on average by 33% of users.
> - 95% of users drag the vertical scrollbar

[Here are some more descriptions about this study](https://blog.mozilla.org/metrics/2010/07/01/firefox-main-window-study-a-heatmap-visualization/)

Comment: I'm amazed by these figures over using the scroll wheel. Is there any indication of how much scrolling was involved in the page? I tend to find users use scrollbar dragging when they need to go a 'long way' and the scroll wheel when they want to slowly scan the page at reading pace

Comment: Sorry, I can't find any details in the study...

Comment: Sorry, didn't expect you to go looking. Link is really useful, thanks for posting. +1